# gitignore a given folder in multiple subfolders

Tags: git

In my web project, there are two node applications, each having a separate node_modules folder.

main_folder has a client folder and server folder, which are two separate node apps.

I have created a .gitignore file inside main folder and I wish to ignore node_modules folders in both node apps. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `node_modules/` to .gitignore in main directory.

Each line in .gitignore represents a pattern that will make git ignore specific files and directories. It should cover all subdirectories as well.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Congratulations on your first reputation gain.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to ignore the `node_modules` subfolder.
You can ignore it in the main folders `.gitignore` file or from
the node apps subfolders `.gitignore` file.

Example folder structure

```
main
|-- client
|   |-- foo
|   |   |-- foo.txt
|   | 
|   |-- bar
|   |   |-- bar.txt
|   |
|   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- modules.txt
|
|-- server
|   |-- foo
|   |   |-- foo.txt
|   | 
|   |-- bar
|   |   |-- bar.txt
|   |
|   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- modules.txt
```

#### Ignore it from the main folder

Add a `.gitignore` file to the `main` folder with the following pattern:

```
/**/node_modules/
```

```
main
|-- ...
|-- .gitignore
```

#### Ignore it from the app subfolders

The patterns from `.gitignore` in subfolders override the patterns from parent folders. This means you can also add a `.gitignore` to each app subfolder with the following pattern:

```
/node_modules
```

```
main
|-- client
|   |-- ...
|   |-- .gitignore
|
|-- server
|   |-- ...
|   |-- .gitignore
```

From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the
> path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level
> files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those
> in lower level files down to the directory containing the file. These
> patterns match relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file. A
> project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its repository,
> containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.